# How can I add SEO to a symfony 1.4 project?

Tags: html, seo, symfony-1.4

I'm currently creating a Symfony project 1.4 and I want to add SEO (Search Engine Optimization).

I already know that my URL should contain the title of the page instead of the ID
but what about other things: meta, images, titles?

Does anybody have good ideas, tips, hints or references? Also hints that are not specific for Symfony could be useful.

Comment: why was I downvoted? this is a good question as there is no proper documentation on how to do this, what to think abouton implementing this in Symfony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this article adequately sums up SEO in Symfony:

http://www.symfonylab.com/about-seo-in-symfony-projects/